# How can I make my background image fit the whole screen?

Tags: css

First the image covered the whole background but kept going over as it was too big

css:

```
body{ 
    background: url("../images/wedding2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
}
```

So then I did this to stop the image from repeating and to fit the background completely but the problem is it leaves a white bottom and doesn't fit the whole background.If I do just background cover it will be too big and get blurry.

Comment: background-size: cover; 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: I did this background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat; everything is fine but the image just has left a little white space at the bottom instead of filling the whole background.If I just do cover so it goes over.Thanks for answering.Can you please help me with this?

Comment: you need to show us code

Comment: I have edited my answer and shown the new code.

Answer (score 0):

we don't have much to work with. But here are the things you could do to prevent a blurry image.

first, make sure the  `background-size` is set to `cover` don't give it a fixed value of size that will cause it to be more blurry

second, Make sure you are using high quality/high resolution image and try to respect the ratio of the image.

By doing that you are preventing the unwanted blurry from the image.

You can find some high-quality images all over the place I recommend using [unsplash](https://unsplash.com/)

if that still not enough you may want to use the `image-rendering` attribute. [image-rendering MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)